# Using 1 SQL to retrieve multiple records or multiple SQL to retrieve individual records

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like ask if there is any performance advantage of 1 over the other.

Here is an example:

```
// suppose I want to retrieve 10000 different records
select * 
from table_a 
where from in (1,2,3,4,5,6 .... 10000)

// alternatively
select * 
from table_a 
where from=1 or from=2 or from=3 ... from=10000
```

compared to

```
select * from table_a where from=1
select * from table_a where from=2
select * from table_a where from=3
.
.
select * from table_a where from=10000
```

What are the scenarios that one will outperform the other?

The `WHERE` clause is simplified here, it may have nested AND and OR clauses.

Comment: in the case as you showed, using single sql statement should have a better performance. you could also simplify the where clause as from <= 10000 (if possible).

Comment: @Shiping, yap my example is oversimplified, what about those with multiple and clauses? I am using contiguous number for simplicity. the actual sql have random numbers that are not contiguous.

Comment: generally speaking, fewer IO accesses, better the performance. of course there're always exceptions.

Comment: @Shiping, in this case the statements are all executed in single DB access

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308280/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-between-and-in-with-mysql-or-in-sql-in

Comment: @sumit, thx for the link, unfortunately it is a separate issue.

Comment: @Mox how can you execute multiple select statements in a single db access?

Comment: @shiping, yes you can, just needs to be comma separated statements.

Comment: @Mox  i got syntax errors when i tried it (with mysql)

Comment: @Mox you may benchmark them to get some ideas.

Comment: i think you should use between keywords

Comment: @ManishSingh , this is just an example, it may not be contiguous. and it can be string not just number

Comment: Oh so sorry i seen your example and i think it is suitable for this

Answer (score 1):

There are many factors beyond your simple example involved.

For your exact example 1 query is better than 1000, because example is simple and against one field. 
 Main factor is network I/O operations, physical and/or logic reads 
and such.

But if you have more WHERE conditions especially when there are joins, that can be questionable what is better.
 And it depends on actual DB tables, relationships, indexes design, types of joins, size of tables and (so and so)...
As general direction in most cases 1 SQL is better, but other factors can be much more important than that.
 All starts from very careful database design. Mistakes there (happen quite often), cost a lot later.
 Usually  1000 queries are better when database was designed badly.

Comment: the actual scenario consist of multiple joins across 4 to 5 tables and may contain 4 to 5 And clauses.

Comment: Then,it depends on nature of those joins, if it is normalized joins (one-to-many Foreign Key to Primary Key) it is good to have indexes on Foreign Key columns as well as indexes on fields involved in Where clause like your `from` column in example (BTW not a good name for column). But count of indexes for one table must be in balance. Too many of them may affect performance of CRUD operations. Physically each Index is another table. So... good luck!