# SQL optimization (group by and max)

Tags: sql, query-optimization

Exist a chance to speedup the below sql query?

```
select 
    max(xtrid) as xtrid
  , jid
from jpltab jl
  inner join rb_cust u 
    on jl.custid = u.custid
where jl.tpe = 'Y'
  and jl.jid in (51, 52, 53, 54, 55)
  and u.org = 'INVCE'
group by jid
order by xtrid desc;
```

thanks

Comment: Adding indexes....

Comment: can you include the execution plan please?

Comment: Since your `jl.jid` in your `Where` clause has consecutive numbers, change that to `Between 51 and 55` instead of the `IN (51, 52, 53, 54, 55)`. This should give you better performance. See here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308280/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-between-and-in-with-mysql-or-in-sql-in

Comment: What database client?

Comment: I would also move "and u.org = 'INVCE'" to your JOIN statement. You only want rb_cust to match jpltab for custid, but ONLY for rb_cust.org='INVCE'. Logically, that will make that initial JOIN a lot smaller, instead of JOINing for every custid and then filtering out for the org. The SQL Optimizer _may_ already handle this for an INNER JOIN, but I don't think it does.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
select jl.jid, max(xtrid) as xtrid
from jpltab jl inner join
     rb_cust u 
     on jl.custid = u.custid
where jl.tpe = 'Y' and
      jl.jid in (51, 52, 53, 54, 55) and
      u.org = 'INVCE'
group by jl.jid
order by xtrid desc;
```

I would start with indexes.  What comes to mind is `jpltab(tpe, jid, custid)` and `rb_cust(custid, org)`.

Answer (score -3):

You can take out '`order by xtrid desc`' as you're already selecting the max

Comment: Yes... you don't need to order the values by group in order to select the max for each group.